# Backbone.js redefines $() and this.el vanishes

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Seems like backbone.js (or Javascript?) has some strange behaviours I didn't expect. This is my (simplified) Backbone View (in CoffeeScript):

```
class Application.Views.Sidebar.SidebarView extends Backbone.View
  el: "#backbone-sidebar"
  template: JST["backbone/templates/sidebar"]

  initialize: () ->
    # Yes, I am currently skipping addOne and addAll functions,
    # because it is not needed to reproduce the problem
    Articles.bind 'all',     @render

    Articles.fetch()

  render: =>
    $(@el).html(@template())
    @
```

The problem is in the `render` function: `@el` is undefined when I run this in the debugger. Also the `$()` function is re-defined by backbone.js to some `getElementById` wrapper. When I use `window.$("#backbone-sidebar")` I get the correct jQuery functionality, but that is just a workaround.

Isn't there a way to get jQuery's `$()`?

And why is `@el` undefined?

Comment: After some debugging, I wasn't able to reproduce the problem itself in jsfiddle.net, but to solve it in my code.

I was calling `window.Sidebar = new Application.Views.Sidebar.SidebarView` at the end of the  declaration of `SidebarView`, even before the Surveys Collection was loaded. Somehow this messed up something. Now I am calling `$ -> window.Sidebar = new Application.Views.Sidebar.SidebarView` and it magically works.

Comment: `#backbone-sidebar` element wasn't in the DOM yet when you called it and that's why it was undefined - when you've changed to create Sidebar instance onDocumentReady target element was already created and it worked

Comment: @TomTu: If `@el` contains a string, why is it influenced by the DOM tree?

Comment: if you pass a selector as an @el it will try to find element representing this selector using `jQuery(selector)` in the DOM tree attached to the document - if it fails it just won't work as element will be undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the comments. I am now able to answer the questions myself. To fix the issues, I did prepended `window.Sidebar = new Application.Views.Sidebar.SidebarView` with `$ ->`, which makes it wait for the DOM tree to load. This is the CoffeeScript equivalent of wrapping it in `$(function() {});`

Further explanation:

**1. this.el vanishes:**

Unlike spine.js (which I used previously), backbone.js seems to look up the selector specified in `el`. If it cannot find the selector, `this.el` will be undefined.

**2. `$()` is redefined**

If you evaluate `$` in the Chrome debugger, it will return some function which does not look like anything useful. I was not able to figure out, what was exactly going on, but `$("some-random-css-selector")` worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why my this.el was disappearing when I was loading part of the page from a template that had the id of the el.